# how to get diffrent data from single column in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

i want to store multiple data with comma separated in single column and get back data with the help of php in different different line 
 like in column view it will looks like this-- toothbrush-1234,glass-1234,
in up there 1234 is product id
i want to get this data in php with separated values each line with its all details.
like

```
   <?php $sql="select product_name form products where product_id=1234" ?>
```

So is it possible to get data and separat it by - and , from single column.

Comment: For comma separated value use `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: My methods for storing data was wrong which i figured it out later

Answer (score 0):

You want to display your comma separated data into separate rows. You can try this.

```
<?
//Here is the complete example of your code by using MYSQLi Object Oriented:
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "select product_id,product_name form products where product_id=1234";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $yourData = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $yourData[$row['product_id']] = explode(",",$row['product_name']);
    }

    if(count($yourData) > 0){
        foreach ($yourData as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($value as $productname) {
                echo "Product ID >> ".$key. " -- Product Name >> ".$productname;
            }
        }
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

**Side Note:** If you are using `mysql_*` in your application than i suggest you to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` because `mysql_*` is deprecated and not available in PHP 7.